# Add an element/item to a multidimentional list

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional list filled with an employee and their information.

> Ex: "Jane Smith"  "Manager"  "75,000" "Dallas"

the code I have right now is giving me an out of range exception. 
This `bigROW[i].Add(ownName);` and `bigROW[i][j+1] = newElement;` gives me errors.

```
 //Begin making rows
        for (int i = 0; i < fileRowCount; i++ )
        { 
            string findOwners = "";
            findOwners = file5Data.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            if(DISTINCTOppOwners.Contains(findOwners))
            {

                //Find index of where owner is 
                    int useIndex = 0;
                    useIndex = DISTINCTOppOwners.IndexOf(findOwners); 

                 //Add their name to Multidimensional list
                  string ownName = DISTINCTOppOwners[useIndex].ToString();
                    //This line give me the ERROR
                    bigROW[i].Add(ownName);

                for (int j = 0; j < fileColCount; j++)
                { 
                     Add Employee information to Multidimensional list
                    string newElement = file5Data.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                    if(ownName != newElement)
                      {

                        if(j ==0)
                        {
                           //Avoid adding their names to the list twice
                          bigROW[i][j+1] = newElement;
                        }

                        bigROW[i][j] = newElement;
                      }
                    }

                }   
        }
```

I tried adding the info to a list called "sublist" then adding it to the BigRow(multidimensional list),but when I cleared the sublist to add a new row it deleted the values from the BigRow.

Comment: Can you try to make a class and for an employee and use a `List<Employee>`? It's better than using a multi dimensional array thingy

Comment: What is `bigROW`?  A `List<T>`, or an array?  Where is it declared/instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried adding the info to a list called "sublist" then adding it to the BigRow(multidimensional list),but when I cleared the sublist to add a new row it deleted the values from the BigRow.

When you add an object to a list what is stored is a reference, not the contents of the object.  Instead of clearing `sublist` you should create a new `List` each time.  Otherwise you have an outer list that contains multiple copies of the same list inside.

Refer to [jdweng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34669743/920669) above for an example of this.  In his code the `ToList` call creates an new `numbers` list for each line, so that each row has its own `List` of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication64
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\n" +
                "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19\n" +
                "20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29\n" +
                "30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39\n" +
                "40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49\n";

            List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string inputline = "";

            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                List<int> numbers = inputline.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
                output.Add(numbers);
            }
        }
    }
}
```